# Cakephp HasOne() table relationship not working

Tags: php, database, cakephp, model

Well, I dont see anything wrong with the code and with the tables but im having trouble displaying the data i need.

given that the tables are already created and populated, here's what i got:

```
class Business extends AppModel
    {
        public $name = "Business";
        public $useTable = "businesses";

        public $hasOne = array(
        'user_profiles' => array(
            'className'     => 'profiles',
            'foreignKey'    => false,
            'conditions' => array('Business.business_id = profiles.user_id')  
        ));
    }
```

the result as i debug it in my controller is this:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Business' => array(
            'business_id' => '1',
            'business_name' => 'sysnet admin',
            'mac1' => '1f',
            'mac2' => 'af',
            'mac3' => '12',
            'mac4' => 'aa',
            'mac5' => '33',
            'mac6' => 'ba',
            'area_id' => '1',
            'latitude' => '',
            'longitude' => null,
            'province_id' => null,
            'max' => '20',
            'upload' => '0',
            'download' => '0',
            'allow_bypass' => '1',
            'bypass_pin' => '0000000',
            'gate_way' => '192.168.88.1',
            'trial' => '0',
            'hasExpired' => '0',
            'isRedirectEnabled' => '0',
            'redirectLink' => 'www.google.com',
            'group_admin_id' => '1',
            'last_access_time' => '2013-05-23 09:15:37'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Business' => array(
            'business_id' => '89',
            'business_name' => 'Panthera',
            'mac1' => 'd4',
            'mac2' => 'ca',
            'mac3' => '6d',
            'mac4' => '65',
            'mac5' => '60',
            'mac6' => '8b',
            'area_id' => '1',
            'latitude' => '14.5580',
            'longitude' => '121.0183',
            'province_id' => '1',
            'max' => '20',
            'upload' => '0',
            'download' => '0',
            'allow_bypass' => '1',
            'bypass_pin' => 'X7veJ2p',
            'gate_way' => '172.16.88.1',
            'trial' => '0',
            'hasExpired' => '0',
            'isRedirectEnabled' => '0',


            'redirectLink' => 'www.google.com',
                'group_admin_id' => '2',
                'last_access_time' => '2013-05-23 09:15:52'
            )
        ),
....
}
```

what seems to be the problem? I need also to the user profiles to be displayed with its matching business record. Please help. Ive googled answers but Im coding the same lines so I dunno where the problem resides.

Answer (score 4):

You are not creating relations according to the Cake conventions.

```
    public $hasOne = array(
    'user_profiles' => array(
        'className'     => 'profiles',
        'foreignKey'    => false,
        'conditions' => array('Business.business_id = profiles.user_id')  
    ));
```

vs

```
    public $hasOne = array(
    'UserProfile' => array(
        'className'     => 'Profile',
        'foreignKey'    => false,
        'conditions' => array('Business.business_id = Profile.user_id')  
    ));
```

Comment: I'm using Cake v3 and both the array-key as the 'className' value are plural in my case, just fyi.

Comment: This was years ago, probably cake 1.2 or 1.3.

Comment: Yes I figured as much, that's why I tried providing 'up-to-date' info for people looking for fresh answers.